# Connect to Dockerized IIS remotely

Tags: iis, docker, windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows

I have run an IIS from the official image (https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/)
on windows Server 2016

Is there any way to connect to that IIS from an IIS Manager so I could have a GUI Access to that IIS?

Comment: it seems there is a solution on https://github.com/Microsoft/iis-docker/issues/16 ,I haven't test it yet

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for you, but I do have a recommendation:

The core concept behind Docker is that all your application configuration is expressed as code. I recommend creating a Dockerfile (one per service) which uses `FROM microsoft/iis` and configure the site within, including all site files. This ensures that wherever your created image is launched, it will run exactly as you designed.

Docker is a paradigm shift. I wouldn't recommend expecting things to work exactly as they did before.

Comment: you are right, I wanted this feature to help me figure out why my site gave 500 error and found the solution and implement it in my dockerfile. however finally I found (with some difficulties) the problems

Comment: for me, the problem was a module that the site uses but was not installed on IIS by default, so installing that module from dockerfile solved the problem.Someone suggest a way for connecting to IIS remotely here: https://github.com/Microsoft/iis-docker/issues/16 that I haven't try it yet .if you have still some problems, I think you could open another thread for it

Answer (score 0):

Use the following docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis

SHELL [ "powershell" ]

#setup Remote IIS management
RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Service; \
    New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\software\microsoft\WebManagement\Server -Name EnableRemoteManagement -Value 1 -Force; \
    Set-Service -Name wmsvc -StartupType automatic;

#Add user for Remote IIS Manager Login
RUN net user iisadmin Password~1234 /ADD; \
    net localgroup administrators iisadmin /add;
```

Build it using `docker build -t iisremote .`

Run it using `docker run --name remoteiis -d iisremote`

Get the IP address of the container using `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}' remoteiis`

Connect to the container in IIS using the IP address optioned above

[image]

[image]

and the username and password used in the dockerfile

[image]

If you do not have the option in IIS to connect to a server, then you will need to install IIS Manager for Remote Administration from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41177). See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/116395/iis-manager-connect-to-another-server-win7-to-win2008-server/) serverfault question for more info.

#### Note

When I tried creating a container directly from the IIS image (without the local dockerfile), connecting to the container using a terminal, and running the same powershell commands (that are in the dockerfile above) directly in the container terminal it does not work.

#### Source

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/iis-remote-management-for-docker-containers/

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution to it, which contains of following parts. 
1. You need to create local username/password in Container Image
2. You need to install IIS configuration tools
Detailed instructions are in walkthrough below
https://github.com/artisticcheese/artisticcheesecontainer/wiki